# Почему выводится предупреждение Warning: Missing argument...?

Tags: php

Есть код:

```
    class addAd{
      public $ads_o = array();

      public function addAd($data){
         return $this->ads_o[]=$data;
      }
   }

 $addAd = new addAd();
```

Выводится сообщение:1)

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for addAd::addAd(), called in /var/www/public_html/newEmptyPHP.php on line 16 and defined in /var/www/public_html/newEmptyPHP.php on line 10

2)

> Notice: Undefined variable: data in /var/www/public_html/newEmptyPHP.php on line 11

Если изменить имя метода на:

```
    `public function new_method_name($data){
         return $this->ads_o[]=$data;
      }`
```

сообщения пропадают. Почему когда совпадает имя класса и метода появляется сообщени об ошибке?

Comment: потому что в php4 имя конструктора совпадало с именем класса, т.е. если класс `addAd`, значит и конструктор `addAd`, вы создаете объект, но не передаете в конструктор значение, отсюда и ошибка. Для совместимости, php5+ поддерживает и старый синтаксис php4, отсюда и ошибка в новой версии. Чтобы избавиться от нее, можно использовать дефолтное значение (`public function addAd($data = array())`), либо изменить имя метода

Comment: ну и будет хорошо, если уже сейчас познакомитесь со стандартами [PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/), ваш код сейчас "не очень" + зачем вам `public` для переменной `$ads_o`?

Comment: Использование классов — это ещё не ООП. Точно так же как использование функций — это ещё не функциональное программирование. Убрал лишнюю метку.

Comment: @VladD, ок, а если бы вопрос был в [таком виде](http://pastebin.com/13LSUHTV) - это имело бы отношение к oop? Базовый класс создается с ошибкой, но потомок спокойно работает, почему так? Вроде про наследование, вроде к oop отношение имеет, но проблема-то одна и та же - конструктор родителя коряво указали. Т.е. я не вижу особых причин убирать эту метку. Тем более, что если добавить в класс a строчку `public function __construct() {}` ошибок уже не будет

Comment: @BOPOH: Вопрос по ООП — это например «стоит ли для такой-то иерархии классов использовать композицию или наследование?». Вопросы об ошибках имплементации, если дизайн ясен, как мне кажется, не относятся к ООП.

Comment: @VladD, ну еще раз ок, а какую метку тогда поставить, чтобы было ясно, что вопрос именно про классы? Тег "классы" - это css, тега "класс" я не вижу, кроме "oop" я других подходящих не вижу

Comment: @Ильнар, еще исправить можно как я чуть выше указал: *если добавить в класс `addAd` строчку `public function __construct() {}` ошибок уже не будет*

Comment: Спасибо. Если хотите можете продублировать комментарий в ответ.